# Static fields in kotlin

Tags: android, static, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and trying to convert my android activities to Kotlin, but I've no Idea how to declare a field as static.
I want to convert the following code...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static String TAG = "MainActicity";

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ....

   }

....
}
```

Can anybody just help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you did not even try googling it.

Comment: @awd Yes, I did, but, the official doc is hard to understood by a 14 year old student :'-(

Comment: Try with @JvmField . That works as a static

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple activity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "MainActivity"
    }

}
```

Comment: That's not the exact thing, I just want any field to be static

Comment: @Abhijeet Soni, you should use companion object :)